# Can you make desktop shortcuts to Seamless mode Windows apps in VirtualBox on OSX?

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox

Running the latest version of VirtualBox on OSX and hosting a Windows virtual machine.  Is there a way to put shortcuts on your Mac desktop for the Windows apps that you run in seamless mode?

I can't find a way to do this, so every time I want to newly launch a Windows app in seamless mode I have to access the full Windows desktop, start the app and hit <kbd>HostKey</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.  Really a pain for apps that you want to run in seamless mode all time.

Comment: A similar problem has been solved for Ubuntu host, and several commands seem to be similar also in OSX hosts. Take a look at this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/153894/launch-an-application-in-windows-from-the-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 1):

See the manual here regarding using VBoxManage and the guestcontrol option. (Specifically 'execute')

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-guestcontrol

Exerpt:

> execute, which allows for executing a program/script (process) which
>   already is installed and runnable on the guest. This command only
>   works while a VM is up and running and has the following syntax:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol <vmname>|<uuid> exec[ute]
            --image <path to program> --username <name>
            [--passwordfile <file> | --password <password>]
            [--environment "<NAME>=<VALUE> [<NAME>=<VALUE>]"]
            [--verbose] [--timeout <msec>]
            [--wait-exit] [--wait-stdout] [--wait-stderr]
            [--dos2unix] [--unix2dos]
            -- [[<argument1>] ... [<argumentN>]]
```

Comment: -1 This is not a complete answer